# "Login with your Facebook id" featureusing http redirect from native mac os app using cocoa

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

On developer.facebook.com, for facebook login feature I see resources for ios, web and even tvos but I dont see any good resource or example for native mac os. "Login with Google" feature example code (https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS) with http redirect option works but I am not able to use that flow for facebook. I am sure this is a solved problem and am looking for any links or leads on how I can implement this feature with facebook from my mac os app.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the link, the docs say -
"To use Facebook Login in a desktop app, you'll need to be able to embed a web browser (sometimes called a webview) within the app to perform the login process.", so I ended up creating a webview in my app (some articles say this is not a best practice, need to research more on this)

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8252 - RFC on oauth for native apps says that using webview is not recommended.

Comment: It's the only way for desktop apps using Facebook login. Unless you want to follow the RFC, handle login on a website inside the browser, and then have users copy&paste their access token from there over into your app ... not really comfortable, and probably not much more secure either.

Comment: "It's the only way for desktop apps using Facebook login" - ya realized that and ended up creating a webview inside my app. Must say that the documentation for facebook login in native apps needs to be updated and(or) streamlined, took me a while to understand and  get a working flow implemented.